# Listview with the same data over several columns

Tags: c#, listview, asp.net-3.5

I have a list that contains names.

I would like to create a listview that will display these name, three to a row.

I am unsure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a GroupTemplate. Here's an example from [4GuysFromRolla.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150712/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/010208-1.aspx)

```
<asp:ListView ID="ProductList1" runat="server"
   DataSourceID="ProductDataSource"
   GroupItemCount="3" ItemPlaceholderID="itemsGoHere"
   GroupPlaceholderID="groupsGoHere">

   <LayoutTemplate>
      <p>
         <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupsGoHere"></asp:PlaceHolder>
      </p>
   </LayoutTemplate>

   <GroupTemplate>
      <ol>
         <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemsGoHere"></asp:PlaceHolder>
      </ol>
   </GroupTemplate>

   <ItemTemplate>
      <li><%#Eval("ProductName")%></li>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```